Are Molor and Morath the same person?
In Star Trek, many of the references to the historical Klingon Kahless mention his interaction with opposing historical figures, specifically, Molor and Morath. These Figures have similar names, and both are negatively portrayed in most canon mentions. Per Memory Alpha, Molor is mentioned as a tyrant, and Morath is typically regarded as Kahlesses brother who he killed. However, the Memory Alpha Page for Morath lists Moraths father as “Molor’s Father.”
What is the distinction between these characters?

I can't see any good canon references that the two are related. One rebelled against the other, so it seems more likely that they were contemporaries, rather than family.

'the Memory Alpha Page for Morath lists Moraths father as “Molor’s Father.”' - not any more it doesn't

Molor and Morath are different people.
Molor was a tyrant defeated and killed by Kahless, per stories related in multiple episodes of TNG and DS9. (TNG: Firstborn, TNG: Rightful Heir, DS9: You Are Cordially Invited, DS9: The Sword of Kahless)
TNG: Rightful Heir

Kahless (clone):I went into the mountains, all the way to the volcano at Kri'stak. THere I cut off a lock of my hair and thrust it into the river of molten rock which poured from the summit. The hair began to burn. Then I plunged it into the lake of Lusor and twisted it into this sword. And after I used it to kill the tyrant Molor I gave it a name: bat'leth. The sword of honor.

TNG: Firsborn

WORF: It is the tyrant Molor. He was so strong no one could stand against him.

DS9: You Are Cordially Invited

WORF: The tradition dates back to the wedding of Kahless and Lukara, who were nearly killed by Molor's troops moments after they were married.

DS9: The Sword of Kahless
(discussing the recovered bat'leth)

WORF: With it he slew Molor, conquered the Fek'lhri and forged the first Empire. And now I hold it in my hands.

Meanwhile, Morath was Kahless' brother who had dishonored the family, and who Kahless did not explicitly kill in the stories relayed to us on-screen.
TNG: New Ground
(Worf is chastising Alexander for lying)

ALEXANDER: Kahless?
WORF: And his brother, Morath. They fought for twelve days and twelve nights because Morath had broken his word and brought shame to his family.

TNG: Firstborn

K'MTAR: Kahless was determined to teach his brother a lesson because he had told a lie. But Morath refused to fight him and instead ran away. Kahless pursued him across the valleys, over the mountains, and down to the edge of the sea. And there on the shore, they fought for...
ALEXANDER: Twelve days, twelve nights. I know, I've heard this story before.

Kahless forged the first batl'leth and slew Molor on/near a volcano, while he fought with Morath on a sea shore. No mention is made of Morath being slain or bat'leths being involved in the Kahless/Morath story.
Molor is only ever mentioned again (and we sort of see a cult of his followers) in Discovery: Will You Take My Hand?, and at no point during that episode does anyone remark that Molor and Kahless were brothers. Morath seems to have only been mentioned in the two quotes provided above.
